# Python iterate through an 2dDarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array like

```
    grid = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now based on the point where there is `1`, I wanna create a new array and save the distance to all the points from it. Example

```
dp = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
      [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
      [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`   not sure what I'm missing.

```
def minTotalDistance(grid):
    dp = [[0]*len(grid[0]) for _ in range(len(grid))]

    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[0])):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                dfs(i, j, dp, 1)
                
    print dp 
    
def dfs(i, j, dp, val): 
    if i < 0 or i >= len(dp) or j < 0 or j >= len(dp[0]):
        return 0 
    dp[i][j] = val
    dfs(i - 1, j, dp, val+1)
    dfs(i + 1, j, dp, val+1)
    dfs(i, j - 1, dp, val+1)
    dfs(i, j + 1, dp, val+1)
    

grid = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
minTotalDistance(grid)
```

Comment: You need to maintain a set of visited cells. Otherwise your dfs will be moving back and forth between the same cells.

Comment: I think your problem is that the function `dfs()` needs an extra return value other than the terminal recursion condition. Also its not clear what results you get in `dp` if `grid` contains more than one `1`? I would have gone down the [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) route and leveraged `cityblock` by converting the inidices of `grid` into a 2D coordinate array.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is with your recursive calls. For example when you call the `dfs(0, 0, dp, val)` will call `dfs(0-1, 0, dp, val)` which returns but then it will call `dfs(1, 0, dp, val)` which then calls `dfs(1 - 1, 0, dp, val)`. Here dp and val are irrelevant in terms of the recursion as they don't terminate the function in any way. Note that the last call is equivalent to the first call in terms of i and j which just repeat the cycle until the call stack exceeds the memory boundary and you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need some condition to stop the recursion. For instance, only process cells if they are unprocessed or if the current path constitutes an improvement.

```
def dfs(i, j, dp, val): 
    if  not (0 <= i < len(dp) and 0 <= j < len(dp[0])):
        return 0 
    # only process if improvement or unprocessed
    if dp[i][j] == 0 or val < dp[i][j]: 
        dp[i][j] = val
        dfs(i - 1, j, dp, val+1)
        dfs(i + 1, j, dp, val+1)
        dfs(i, j - 1, dp, val+1)
        dfs(i, j + 1, dp, val+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using recursion, you must make sure to never enter a recursion loop where a recursive function call itself with some parameters and inside that call, call again itself with the original parameter.

Here when computing `df(i, j, ...)` you call `dfs(i-1, j, ...)` and in that call you have `dfs(i+1, j, ...)` which gives the original point => infinite loop!

You should either make sure to always increase indices, or to have a distinctive value for uninitialized points and break the recursion as soon as a point has already received a value.